# InsertSymbol in Word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm creating a custom Microsoft Word mailmerge console application using C#.  My only problem is trying to use the InsertSymbol command (from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word).  The purpose is to drop in a checked box symbol if the field value is true, and an empty box if the field value is false.

Microsoft has a definition of this command [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertsymbol%28office.11%29.aspx) with no concrete examples.

The way I have my command set up is this:

```
Object oFont = "Wingdings";

Object oUnicode = "true";

Object oBias = Word.WdFontBias.wdFontBiasDontCare;

oWord.Selection.InsertSymbol(254, ref oFont, ref oUnicode,ref oBias);
```

When I try to run that command, I get the error "This is not a valid number."  There are not a lot of examples of this command online and I was hoping for some ideas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. My problem was surrounding the value of oUnicode with quotes.  I removed the quotes and now it works perfectly.  I just wanted to let people know that it's working now.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Robert for sharing this solution:

```
Object oFont = "Wingdings";
Object oUnicode = true;
Object oBias = Word.WdFontBias.wdFontBiasDontCare;
oWord.Selection.InsertSymbol(254, ref oFont, ref oUnicode,ref oBias);
```

It works well!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not get your code to Work. But then it hit me, that VSTO has a different perception of false and true: True is 1 (the number 1) so in the above code you should set:

```
oUnicode = 1;//NOT "true" and that IS 1 truth
```

Doing that I got the code working correctly.
That also communicates with the error description ('not a valid number')